# How to implement Snowflake 'Task' in DBT

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse, dbt

We are using snowflake from sometime in our company. We have made couple of tasks in Snowflake who run on schedule daily and refresh tables data.
How can we achieve same is DBT?
Issue no. 2:
Also, this task uses COPY INTO command of Snowflake to read from stage and create table. How can i achieve that in Snowflake.

Comment: Assuming you aren't asking for a tutorial on dbt, what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using two options.

1. You can use DBT Cloud. A paid cloud version of DBT. where you can setup the model/models and DBT cloud will run them as per schedule.
2. Another inexpensive process is use some on-prem scheduler and dbt non cloud core version.
   Install the scheduler tools and dbt core in any server. And then convert your process into models if not done already. Call the dbt commands using PS or Shell. Schedule the job using your tool.

Free schedulers can be - Apache Airflow, Jenkins, or Ansible.

Comment: I don’t believe OP is asking about orchestrating DBT jobs. They are asking about creating Snowflake task processes with DBT.

Comment: hmm, i thought this is orchestrating jobs `couple of tasks in Snowflake who run on schedule daily and refresh tables data`. Even if they want to do anythingin DBT, they can use option1.

Comment: You actually may be right. I can see your point after rereading. I guess OP will need to clarify.